# Protocol Buffers with dll programing c++

Tags: c++, dll, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to write a plugin for rFactor in C++ and I'd like to use Protocol Buffers for serialize all the data and send it with sockets. I tried protobuf succesfuly with other projects I developed but I get some error with this example.

> Error C2440   'initializing': Can't convert 'void *(__cdecl *)(size_t)'
>   to 'void *(__fastcall *)(size_t)' InternalsPlugin
>   c:..\include\google\protobuf\arena.h 150

I don't understand why is happening because it worked properly with other projects...I'm lost...any ideas?

Comment: protoc does not decorate its generated classes with declspec(dllimport) or export so you'll want a complete protobuf environment within each dll that uses it. That's going to mean statically linking your DLL linking with the protobuf libraries. (unless it produces different code on windows?) You'll also want to avoid sharing protobuf messages between dlls.

Answer (score 1):

windows has different calling conventions. When calling a function one needs to specify the calling convention used. In your case your function pointer is set up to use the __cdecl calling convention (the default in C or C++ on windows).

To solve your problem, you will probably need to include an explicit calling convention declaration in your function pointer declaration.

Without more details, I cannot provide better help.

Comment: that error is from a Header file from protocol buffers, so...I don't understand why I should change nothing in that header. The header is arena.h, i will provide what ever you think is necessary.As I said, I'm lost...